# How do i sort out the loading delay with my stream? phonegap build

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-build

```
<audio id="stream" preload='none'>
        <source src="http://195.10.228.6:8035/canal.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <a href="#" id="audioControl">play!</a>

<script>
var stream = document.getElementById('stream'),
ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

ctrl.onclick = function () {

// Update the Button
var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'pause!';
ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'play!' : 'pause!';

// Update the Audio
var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
stream[method]();

// Prevent Default Action
return false;
};
</script>
```

So the code above works fine in the way that it allows me to play/pause the live stream of a radio show. However the only problem/minor issue is to do with loading. You must wait on the app after it is opened to load for around 10seconds all features of the app are accessible during this time. Also if you hit the play button before the stream has loaded it won't load unless the app is closed and re-opened. i've not tried it with refreshing as i haven't built that feature in yet. So i'm not sure whether that would work in the app.

Basically the question is how do i stop this delay? or allow it to load during/after someone hits play?

phonegap build btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen a few reports of this but never a solid answer. One thing to check is the buffer time setting on your stream server. Could be server side and not client side.

As for disabling the play button until it is actually already playing, try this:

```
idOfYourAudioTag.addEventListener("playing", function() {
    //enable your button here
});
```

If the "playing" event is fired too early, you can try the other event listeners. See the events section in this URL: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: Well nevermind then i think i'll just provide a small warning or something just like "please allow 10 seconds for stream to load before trying to start" etc there is other things to do on the app afterall

Comment: Also, look into disabling the play button until the stream loads to prevent the user from breaking it.

Comment: Great idea. Just need to find out how to check or disable it for 10 seconds after start up perhaps

Comment: Updated answer to provide idea of how to detect the state.